# Keycloak load testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

I have deployed keycloak as a standalone server and wanted to load test on it. I have very less knowledge about how to load test using jmeter. Gone through [this resource](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) but it is hard for me to understand it.

Can anybody explain on how can i actually do it ?

EDIT: I made a simple api that will authenticate using keycloak. So what i did is deploy the api in another server and used jmeter to get the auth token from keycloak and use that token to authenticate to the api. I did as much threads as possible as a way of load testing.